# My Pods Terminated with code 137 and reason Error

Tags: kubernetes

I've Kubernetes v1.28 with 4 nodes of 2 CPU and 4GB each. I am having problems with the majority of pods that I am deploying in this environment. The pods start running normally but will be terminated and restarted frequently. I have set the resource for 2 CPUs for this service and solved it, but I cannot believe that I will reserve 2 CPUs for a simple service. Could you help me?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: alpine
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 256Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 2Gi
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - "-c"
      - "sleep 60m"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: alpine
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  restartPolicy: Always
```

```
Name:             alpine
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             ip-10-0-1-39.ec2.internal/10.0.1.39
Start Time:       Fri, 27 Oct 2023 11:51:19 +0000
Labels:           <none>
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.3.162
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.3.162
Containers:
  alpine:
    Container ID:  containerd://872f89aa8f8fd401c59f0c1318cb1496766cf726e200c7b4f65abd213f7386f6
    Image:         alpine
    Image ID:      docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:eece025e432126ce23f223450a0326fbebde39cdf496a85d8c016293fc851978
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      sleep 60m
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 27 Oct 2023 11:53:09 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Fri, 27 Oct 2023 11:51:20 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 27 Oct 2023 11:53:08 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:        500m
      memory:     256Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-zzg7m (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-zzg7m:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                 From               Message
  ----    ------          ----                ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled       2m5s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/alpine to ip-10-0-1-39.ec2.internal
  Normal  Pulling         2m5s                kubelet            Pulling image "alpine"
  Normal  Pulled          2m4s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "alpine" in 428ms (428ms including waiting)
  Normal  Killing         46s                 kubelet            Stopping container alpine
  Normal  Created         15s (x2 over 2m4s)  kubelet            Created container alpine
  Normal  Started         15s (x2 over 2m4s)  kubelet            Started container alpine
  Normal  SandboxChanged  15s                 kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  Pulled          15s                 kubelet            Container image "alpine" already present on machine
```

**Same image running in my docker desktop, if you see, the resource used is so low, I cannot undestand why k8s is killing my pod because of resource**
[image]

**k9 logs**
[image]

Comment: There are a couple of unusual things in this setup – I wouldn't normally expect to see a bare Pod, or an unmodified `alpine` image, or `sh -c 'sleep 60'` as the main container command.  If this setup is still seeing processes getting killed off then it seems unlikely to be a programming-related problem (nothing here is actually running code you've written).

Comment: Yes, I had made a post with the more real scenario, however I preferred to delete it and make this one with this pure image without the nodejs application behind it, to avoid raising the hypothesis that it might be a problem in the application, since the Pure container is restarting from time to time without a clear reason.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. After checking the container metric, I could see the container is getting down using only 38 MB of memory. I undestood the problem could be with the Docker resource manager. I have changed docker to the containerd on all nodes and solved the problem.